# Adding a signature with an image/logo and *not* creating an attachment icon

Tags: exchange-2007, html, outlook-2003, mime, email

My company uses Outlook 2003/2007 on Exchange, and they want to standardize on a signature format.

What is the best way to add an image to a signature with these features (in order of priority):

1. Not show an attachment icon (in a majority of email clients)
2. Render as an image (some clients block external URL's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to send HTML emails and base64 encode the image that you want to use. This shouldn't show up as an attachment, but most modern email clients will successfully render the image.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1761/embedding-images-in-email/

Comment: budde It appears to not work in most email clients.

Comment: Then you'll need to go full HTML with external images. Otherwise you're going to get the attachment icon